# Reverse Alexa rank to website url function

Tags: php, alexa-internet

My question is whether there is any PHP code for looking up the website url for a given numerical Alexa ranking ?

I have alexa ranking php code that finds the alexa ranking number for a given site, but I'm trying to figure out what to do if I want to go the other direction and determien for example what is the URL of the 34.392 website on Alexa? Is there a way that this could be done?

Comment: Reworded question to read more clearly, and to be less of a resource request question.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041371/alexa-api. Anyone tried the Alexa API to see if this is supported?